# GetX Get.arguments always returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-getx

I have an issue with routing. I am using GetX and Get.arguments is always returning null.
I am defining my routes in route_generator.dart

```dart
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.splashScreen:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => const SplashPage(),
          binding: SplashBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
      case AppRoutes.unauthenticated:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => const UnauthenticatedPage(),
          binding: UnauthenticatedBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
      case AppRoutes.login:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => const LoginPage(),
          binding: LoginBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
      case AppRoutes.register:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => const RegisterPage(),
          binding: RegisterBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
      case AppRoutes.dashboard:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => DashboardPage(0),
          binding: DashboardBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
      case AppRoutes.editProfile:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => const EditProfilePage(),
          binding: EditProfileBinding(),
          transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
        );
      default:
        return GetPageRoute(
          page: () => const SplashPage(),
          binding: SplashBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
    }
  }
}
```

here is my main.dart where I am specifying routes

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Test App',
      defaultTransition: Transition.rightToLeft,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      darkTheme: Themes.darkTheme,
      theme: Themes.lightTheme,
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.splashScreen,
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
```

then when I am trying to launch a new screen using a route it works properly just I cannot retrieve arguments as they are null

list_view.dart

```
onTap: () => {
              Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.exerciseDetail, arguments: [
                {'exercise': exercise}
              ])
            },
```

print returns null
detail_view_controller.dart

```
  @override
  void onInit() {
    dynamic arguments = Get.arguments;
    print(arguments);
    super.onInit();
  }
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: instead of onGenerateRoute use getPages at GetMaterialApp

Comment: but how do I deal with bindings then?

Comment: GetPage has a binding argument

Comment: did you got any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can set arguments using settings in `RouteGenerator` something like this.

```
Navigator(
   key: Get.nestedKey(1),
   onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
   Get.routing.args = settings.arguments; // <---- this line 
   return PageRedirect(settings: settings).page();
   },
  )
```

[Example](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/179#issuecomment-900630950)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Literally hours for just a line...

Answer (score -1):

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.splashScreen:
        return GetPageRoute(
         
          // use settings.arguments
          page: () => const SplashPage(arguments: settings.arguments),
          binding: SplashBinding(),
          transition: Transition.fade,
        );
```

Comment: Is there any way we can use `Get.arguments` ?

Comment: This would require the SplashPage to have a key needed. Also, it fails as well with null.

Answer (score -2):

Try passing arguments with `out [ ]`.
Such as these arguments: `{'exercise': exercise}`

You can also try like this:

```
arguments:{'exercise': exercise, 'name':max}
```

And can access them:

```
Print(Get.arguments['name']);
// output max
```

Comment: Tried that, always null, the object being passed is not a problem, even when passing basic int it is null